# IE9 CSS Issues with arrangment of two items in li

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, list

have a look of this please:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dspJ5/1/embedded/result/)

in firefox, chrome, opera is code ok,
but in ie9 shift the numbers, see picture please.
left is everything ok, right is ie9.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/asdlj.png/

i can´t solve the problem, need help :(

HTML

```
<ul id="category">
    <li>
        <p>
            35
        </p>
        Spiele
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>
            352
        </p>
        Puppen
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#category {
    float:left;
    background:#e8e8e8;
}
#category li {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#category p {
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

I've simplified the code considerably.

Stenzg

Comment: why is 1 part of the content wrapped with p tag and the other one not?

Comment: Dude, why do you use `<p>` here?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the spaces in between the `<li>` and `<p>` tags? I don't have IE9 so I can't check.

Comment: delete spaces don´t work.
because to adjust the numbers to the right side of the li element, did I use p wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would qualify as a time to use a `<table>`. This is a much cleaner and compatible way of handling this particular issue. You won't run into any browser issues. Try this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Spiele</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Puppen</td>
    <td>352</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And some basic CSS :

```
table {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nFcrW/)

Check out the MDN table [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table) if you're not familiar with using them.